# Deleted Windows Service is still in the Task Manager

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I am new to C# and created a test Windows Service. I installed the service using the following command in the Visual Studio 2015 command prompt (run as Administrator).

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319> InstallUtil.exe "D:\FILEPATH\WindowsReportService.exe"
```

The above command had installed my windows service which I confirmed by going to the `services.msc`

**PROBLEM:** Since the service was only for learning, now I want to uninstall that service. To remove the service I have done the following steps:

1. Run Regedit.exe.
2. Go to the registry entry "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services"
3. Looked for the service that I wanted to delete and deleted it.

***But even after doing the above steps, `My Windows Service` is appearing in the task manager as well as in the `services.msc`.***

Comment: That's not how you uninstall a service... See the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd8zc8ha(v=vs.110).aspx In short, run `installutil /u <yourproject>.exe`

Comment: @Equalsk: Thanks, it worked :)

Comment: Besides being the wrong solution, the CurrenControlSet registry hive is generated by the system. It's not materialized into the filesystem-backed database. Any changes you make are lost on the next reboot.